# ReactJS - component to change what is rendered by another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am creating a reactJS app that will show a list of mobile phones. I am currently calling an API, setting state to the response, and then displaying the contents. I am now looking to add sort order to this but am having difficulty.

When the user goes to /phones/Apple/iPhone, the routing will render the following component that calls the api, sets the state and passes the data to the results component...

```
export default class Phones extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: null,
        make: this.props.params.make || null,
        model: this.props.params.model || null
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    const makeQuery = this.state.make ? this.state.make + '/' : '';
    const modelQuery = this.state.model ? this.state.model : '';
    const fetchUrl = '/api/phones/' + makeQuery + modelQuery;

    fetch(fetchUrl, {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then(json=> {
                this.setState({data: json});
            });
        }
    });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.data) {
        const currentUrl = this.props.location.pathname;

        return (
            <section className="phones">
                <Filters 
                    data={this.state.data}
                    currentUrl={currentUrl} />
                <Results 
                    data={this.state.data} />
            </section>
        )
    }
}
}
```

The Results Component will map through the data and render the list of phones.

In the Filters Component I then have a dropdown that allows user to sort the results by price value, and this sets the state too.

```
export default class Filters extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: 0
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e})
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Price</p>
            <select onChange={this.onChange}>
                <option value='asc'>low to high</option>
                <option value='desc'>high to low</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I do not know how I can apply this filter to the component which renders the results, and what is the best way to go about this?

I have started reading in redux, but am confused if the phones data and filters should be in a store as it is temporary and will change if they go to another page i.e /phones/Samsung/Galaxy/

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in React, a parent container will handle state for all sub-components - data and props flow in one direction, down through the component tree.

Redux offers a way to give containers access to a method for updating state.

[This page from the Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#usage-with-react) provide instructions for how to integrate with React.

Redux provides a single object that contains the entire application state. Then an additional NPM module, `react-redux`, provides two functions for "connecting" a component to global Redux state: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

Using this approach, you can have your Filters container set a toggle in global state:

```
state = {
  phones: [],
  sortBy: 'price',
  sortOrder: 'asc',
}
```

Or similar. You can then use `mapStateToProps` to gain access to the sort state slices, and `mapDispatchToProps` to "dispatch" actions that update the state.

The Redux docs are excellent, and written with simplicity and beginners in mind.

Comment: That's great, thank you. I have read through the docs and understand (i think), was especially helpful having an example with an API involved.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of ways to do this.  You mentioned you're just beginning to look into Redux, and I'd encourage you to keep on that path. It will help you much in the world of application state management.  That said, if you are doing this with just React:

1. The parent component is Phones, so write a helper method in `Phones` to keep track of the filter (make sure you set a default filter state for when the component first constructs or mounts like you did with make and model):

   `setFilter(filter) {
     this.setState({filter});
   }`
2. Pass the `filter` from the `Phones` component state to both the `Filters` and `Results` components. Also pass the `setFilter` class method into the child `Filters` component (All this is done in your `Phones` component's `render` method):

   ```
   return (
       <section className="phones">
           <Filters
               filter={this.state.filter}
               onChange={this.setFilter} 
               data={this.state.data}
               currentUrl={currentUrl} />
           <Results 
               data={this.state.data}
               filter={this.state.filter}/>
       </section>
   )
   ```
3. Change your `Filter` component so that its `onChange` event is the `setFilter` handler you passed into it, and the `value` prop in the `<select>` component is the `filter` we passed in (2).

I'll leave 3 to you. I think you can figure it out :).  Note that you now have access to the filter value as a prop in your results class and you can sort in that component.

Answer (score 0):

> I have started reading in redux, but am confused if the phones data and filters should be in a store as it is temporary and will change if they go to another page i.e /phones/Samsung/Galaxy/

Redux is a great solution to this problem.  By externalising the state, both components can easily access the necessary values.

Your concern about the data changing should not be so, as this is an important and common situation for redux stores. Even the [todo list example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) from their documentation implements a filter component similarly to what you are describing.

Another benefit is that if you use the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware (or whichever async middleware you want), you can also move your `fetch` call out of the component so it becomes a little bit simpler.

There are plenty of examples floating around for this kind of setup so I won't bother writing any out for you now, but I'll update this answer for any specific requests in the comments.

Alternatively, you can use callbacks to pass data up and down between components.

This image from [this blog](https://hackernoon.com/10-react-mini-patterns-c1da92f068c5) has is a great illustration of how this can be achieved

[image]